# Does YugaByte support geospatial queries?

Tags: database, geospatial, yugabytedb

Does YugaByte support geospatial queries?

Given REDIS and Postgres API support I thought it might be possible, but I am not seeing any reference to this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in YugaByte DB.

- The YEDIS (Redis-compatible) API does not yet support geo-spatial commands such as [GEOADD](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd). This is not currently in our roadmap. Nevertheless, could you please open a GitHub issue against us for support this?
- The Postgres API is in beta, and do not have Postgis working yet. This is on the roadmap, but please open a separate issue for this as well, so we can get back to you once we know the timelines for this.

One option to implement Geo-spatial queries currently is using Spark or Presto with the YCQL (Cassandra-compatible) API. Does that work for you?

For example, here are some [Presto docs outlining geo-spatial functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html).